Errors and residuals in simple exponential smoothing (state space form) in FPP textbook
I am reading Hyndman & Athanasopoulos "Forecasting: Principles and Practice" 2nd edition (FPP2). (I am aware that 3rd edition exists.) In the chapter about exponential smoothing, section 7.5 discusses simple exponential smoothing with additive errors, ETS(A,N,N). It introduces the residual $e_t:=y_t-\ell_{t-1}$ where $\ell_{t-1}$ is the lagged level from the smoothing equation. Then just a few lines below, there is the following passage:

For a model with additive errors, we assume that residuals (the one-step training errors) $e_t$ are normally distributed white noise with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. A short-hand notation for this is $e_t = \varepsilon_t \sim NID(0,\sigma^2)$; NID stands for “normally and independently distributed”.

And then some of the equations that used $e_t$ are rewritten with $\varepsilon_t$. I am a little confused about the meaning of $e_t = \varepsilon_t$ in the quoted passage. Does it just introduce a new symbol for $e_t$? If so, why not use $\varepsilon_t$ right from the start? Or does $e_t = \varepsilon_t$ carry some meaning of its own, telling us that one object equals another object? If so, what are the implications? Briefly, what is the point of writing $e_t = \varepsilon_t$?
(It does not help that parts of the book appear to be a less than perfectly careful about the distinction between model error (random variable), fitted error/residual (its fitted value) and in- vs. out-of-sample forecast error (random variable or its realization).)

Without having looked into the book again, I think your PS is the answer: $\epsilon_i$ is the random variable, $e_i$ its realization. Does that make sense in the context?

@StephanKolassa, I doubt that could make sense in any case (not only in my context), as that implies a realization is equal to a random variable.

I agree that this one equality $e_t=\epsilon_t$ does not make sense. I am referring to the use of the symbols in other places

When we refer to the residual we use $e_t$. When we introduce a stochastic model, we switch to $\varepsilon_t$ to mean an iid innovation.

@RobHyndman, thank you for the clarification! I am still a little puzzled by $e_t=\varepsilon_t$ and the meaning that this equality is intended to carry in the context of the passage. To start with, is it even correct? Is it not true that the residuals of virtually any model are dependent?

The training residuals of a good model should be iid. At least, that's what we are normally trying to achieve when modelling. For long series, and complicated dynamics, that can be beyond reach. As for the switch in notation, I guess this is partly historical. 20th c exponential smoothing had no stochastic model, and so the equations were simply updating equations based on past residuals. 21st c exp smoothing is based on state space models which look identical in most cases. We emphasise the distinction by changing notation. I'm sure it could be better explained!
